# Sum of row entires of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

So let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1\geq...\geq\lambda_n$, and the sum of all entries is $s$. I'd like to prove that:

If either 1) $\lambda_1=s/n$ or 2) $\lambda_n=s/n$, then the sum of every row equals $s/n$.

I have been trying for hours but couldn't get anywhere. I know that, for $A$, $\lambda_1\geq\frac{s}{n}\geq\lambda_n$, but I can't see why it is helpful.

Comment: Is $\lambda_1$ the largest eigenvalue?

Comment: @JiazhenTan Yes, I edited the description. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The basic fact you need is that $\lambda_\max(A)=\max_{\|x\|=1}x^TAx$ and the RHS is maximised if and only if $x$ is a unit eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue of $A$.

Let $e(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ and $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e$. Then $u$ is a unit vector and $e^TAe=s$. Now, if $\lambda_\max(A)=\frac{s}{n}$, then
$$
u^TAu=\frac{e^TAe}{n}=\frac{s}{n}=\lambda_\max(A)=\max_{\|x\|=1}x^TAx.
$$
Therefore $u$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\frac{s}{n}$, and so is $e$ (because it is a nonzero scalar multiple of $u$). Hence $Ae=\frac{s}{n}e$, i.e. all row sums of $A$ are equal to $\frac{s}{n}$.

The case where $\lambda_\min(A)=\frac{s}{n}$ is similar. You can use the identity $\lambda_\min(A)=\min_{\|x\|=1}x^TAx$ and its extremal properties in this case.